# Android - Merge a transparent png on an Image coming from the camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image

I have a camera preview layer. on top of that i'm moving (drag and drop) and zooming a transparent small image in my app. there i use a image view for the png and use a matrix to zooming.
after zooming and positioning the imageview to the place i want, I need to get a one picture which have the background from the camera preview and the foreground with the zoomed and moved positions of the imageview.

To do this,

I'm Capturing an image via the camera.

then i draw the image in the image view on the image captured from the camera.

I tried with following code but didn't work well.

```
    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d("1", "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            //captured=pictureFile.getAbsoluteFile();                
            picturefilepath=pictureFile.getPath();
            ImageView imgv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.midimage);
            //Matrix ms=imgv.getImageMatrix();

            Bitmap b=overlay(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getPath()), imgv);


            ImageView capturedset= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capturedimage);

            capturedset.setImageBitmap(b);



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("2", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("3", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }



    }
};  

private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp2, ImageView view) {       
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp2.getWidth(), bmp2.getHeight(), bmp2.getConfig());        
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, canvas.getMatrix(), null);        


    view.draw(canvas);


    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Comment: Use a canvas 2 draw the 2 bitmaps on.

Comment: What is the wrong with the overlay method in the code above.

Comment: How about using framelayout with a transparent background to overlay images?